# Error using Template function of one parameter (works with 2)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I am writing a template function to print out the first element of a c-style array.  The function works if there are two template arguments, but it fails if there is only one parameter.

The below code works.  The function correctly computes the size of the c-style array.

```
template<typename dummy, typename T>
void printfunc(const T &c){
    std::cout << sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]) << std::endl;  //prints 5 as desired
}
int main() {

 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 printfunc<int>(arr);
 return 0;
}
```

The below code does not.  It has a compile error using g++2a compiler

```
template<typename T>
void printfunc(const T &c){
    std::cout << sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);   //Compile Error
}
int main() {

 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 printfunc<int>(arr);
 return 0;
}
```

What's more confusing is that the compile error I get with `template<typename T>` is different than if I do the below:

```
void printfunc(const int &c){
    std::cout << sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);  //compile error
}
int main() {

 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 printfunc(arr);
 return 0;
}
```

I just replaced template with a function that calls int, which should be equivalent, but the compiler error is different.

What is going on?

Comment: `printfunc<int>(arr);` wants an `int` but you pass an array.

Comment: The convention on Stack Overflow is that you do **not** change your question in response to answers. The content of the question should remain what was answered so that the answers continue to make sense. (Clarifying edits are OK, but removing the error you asked about is not.) When your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you should accept the best answer and **not** edit "answered" into your topic. The existence of an accepted answer indicates that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

What's going on is that you're trying to use `_T=int`, so the function parameter becomes `const int& c`. There is no such thing as `[0]` on an `int` (or a reference-to-`int`).

(If you were expecting `c[0]` to work because `const int* c` works, recall that *references are not pointers*. References are "other names" for things, for individual objects; pointers point to buffers of zero or one or more objects.)

When the parameter you specify is called `_dummy`, the `_T` is left to be deduced by the compiler, which does not make the same mistake (passing `int` instead of an array type).

Either take out the explicit parameter `<int>`, or use it properly in the function argument (e.g. `const T(&c)[N]` with a `std::size_t` non-type template argument).

By the way, [you are not permitted to use the name `_T`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). I suggest you drop the underscores entirely.

Comment: Thanks Asteriod with Wings.  I have good intuition about, const T(&c)[N], but I wanted to avoid the need for N.  I did as you said and I removed explicit parameter <int>.  I suppose this forces compiler to do extra deduction.  Can you elaborate on why this works?

Comment: @JeremyRoberson It's not complex - the compiler knows the type of the array `arr`, and matches it to the function parameter list, picks it for `T`, and away you go. Just as for any other template parameter or any other type. But you can't treat `arr` as an `int`, because it isn't one.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: @JeremyRoberson If you find this answer helpful, consider accepting it instead of changing the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For this template function

```
template<typename _dummy, typename _T>
void printfunc(const _T &c){
    std::cout << sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]) << std::endl;  //prints 5 as desired
}
int main() {

 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 printfunc<int>(arr);
 return 0;
}
```

the compiler deduces the type of the second template parameter from the supplied argument in the call

```
printfunc<int>(arr)
```

to the type `int( & )[5]`.

For the second template function and the third non-template function

```
template<typename T>
void printfunc(const T &c){
    std::cout << sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);   //Compile Error
}
```

and

```
void printfunc(const int &c){
    std::cout << sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);  //compile error
}
```

the compiler issues an error because you explicitly specified the type template argument `int` for the template function in this call

```
printfunc<int>(arr);
```

but using an expression of the type `int[5]` as the function argument. Or again the non-template function expects lvalue of the type `int`  but you passing an object of the type `int[5]` that implicitly converted to the type `int *`. And moreover you may not use the subscript operator for scalar integer objects

The error messages can be different because in the first case the compiler deals with a template function and in the second case with a non-template function.

That is for the non-template function the compiler can issue an error parsing the function definition where there is used the subscript operator for an object of the type int..

Comment: Ah.  So simple!!  Along with Answers With Wings, this has been completely demystified now!!